# Is there a way to manually retry a HelmRelease for FluxCD HelmOperator?

Tags: fluxcd, gitops

I was just reading https://docs.fluxcd.io/projects/helm-operator/en/stable/helmrelease-guide/debugging/#manually-performing-a-release-to-debug as well as the FAQ, but couldn't figure out how to trigger a retry of a HelmRelease.

My workaround was to commit an insignificant change to the watched release repository just to get helmoperator to pick up a diff. Is there a better way?

Comment: Note, [Helm Operator](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator) has been retired (as of FluxCD v2).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To force a HelmRelease reconciliation, you could use a combination of the `suspend` and `resume` commands.

```
flux suspend hr my-helmrelease -n myhelmrelease-ns
```

```
► suspending helmreleases my-helmrelease in myhelmrelease-ns namespace
✔ helmreleases suspended
```

```
flux resume hr my-helmrelease -n myhelmrelease-ns
```

```
► resuming helmreleases my-helmrelease in my-helmrelease-ns namespace
✔ helmreleases resumed
◎ waiting for HelmRelease reconciliation
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `flux reconcile` command:

```
$ flux reconcile helmrelease

The reconcile kustomization command triggers a reconciliation of a HelmRelease resource and waits for it to finish.
```